# How to find the proper $\alpha$ to satisfy the 80/20 rule for the Paretor Distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose we have the CDF for the Pareto Distribution given by:

$$ P(X \leq x) = 1-\left(\frac{x_m}{x}\right)^\alpha \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; x \geq x_m$$

What is the intuitive way to find the alpha for which the 80/20 rule holds?

Comment: Why can't you just set your expression equal to 0.8 and solve for $\alpha$ ?

Comment: for the 80/20 rule, $\alpha$ is supposed to be 1.16. Also how do you represent 20% of the top population if the support is infinite...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Lorenz curve. From the Wikipedia article on the Pareto distribution, we have $$1-(1-0.8)^{1-{1 \over \alpha}}= 0.2$$ if you now solve this for $\alpha,$ you will find the 1.16 you mentioned.